# Getting error when launching WebGL unity game

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I'm trying to compile my unity game to html (WebGL).
When I open the game I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: createUnityFramework is not defined
at t.loadCode.Module (B03.loader.js:1)
at HTMLScriptElement.s.onload (B03.loader.js:1)
```

I'm running the game on xampp local server.

Googled the error, nothing came up. Please help!

**When I do 'Build and run', it's working properly.

Comment: Try it here: http://exampleform.cf/B03/?i=1

Comment: Please help me out here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem by moving to a non-alpha version of Unity.

Answer (score -2):

Let's start with reading the error msg: `Uncaught **ReferenceError**`. You should look to your variable `createUnityFramework` and make sure it is defined somewhere in your project. Once you do that, you can provide more context.

This might require looking at the documentation for help.